# Помогите разобраться с директориями joomla

Tags: joomla

Доброго времени! Хочу добавить язык в Джумле но у меня закрыты директории от записи! 
В корне сайта и в помине нет таких директорий! а у меня так в конфиге прописано!

```
/home/eplans/domains/abttrans.kz/public_html/logs
/home/eplans/domains/abttrans.kz/public_html/tmp
```

Если меняю к примеру

```
www/abttrans.kz/logs
```

Не работает! Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Директории прописаны от корня сервера. Я не знаю какой джумлой пользуетесь, в 1.5 можно было через меню посмотреть пути, но в любом случае выполните скрипт

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>
```

и вам выдастся путь до сайта. возьмите его и добавьте /logs и /tmp это и будут ваши пути

ну и на запись соответственно открывайте папки /logs и /tmp на сайте.

Comment: Идеально))Дай бог вам здоровья!)